# How to identify divergences in pymc3 chain using arviz

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc3

I would like to identify divergences in a chain sampled by pymc3.
Each sample is associated with 1 group and 1 condition (coordinates in the trace).

For the purpose of this example, the following results are only considering 1 chain, and 1 condition (coordinate of the trace).

I am using `Arviz.InferenceData` to plot the trace of samples for a specific variable `a_kg` (where each line represents one group):

```py
import arviz as az

# trace variable coming from pymc3.sample
azdata = az.from_pymc3(
    trace=trace, 
    coords={'group': groups, 'condition': conditions}, 
    dims={'a_kg': ['group', 'condition']}
)
azdata_sel = azdata.sel(chain=[0], condition='Control')
az.plot_trace(azdata_sel, var_names=['a_kg'], divergences='bottom');
```

The trace for each group is plotted below:

[image: trace of divergent chain]

If I understood correctly, the divergences are shown on the bottom of the traces with a rug plot.

If this is correct, there is a divergence around draw 30.
Therefore, I get a slice of samples that has at least one divergence (in this case the slice containing sample 30) to explore this part of the trace in greater detail.

```py
azdata_sel = azdata.sel(draw=slice(25, 35))
az.plot_trace(azdata_sel, var_names=['a_kg'], divergences='bottom')
```

[image: slice of trace]

I would like to identify why the chain diverges to understand better how this model works. However, when I look at the samples for variable `a_kg`, for each group, around draw 30, all values are restricted in a narrow, finite range:

```
array([[7.03689753e+01, 7.08419788e+01, 4.18270946e+01, 5.56815107e+01,
        2.89069656e+01, 3.21847218e+01, 1.72809154e+01, 6.80358410e+00,
        8.27741780e+00, 8.61561309e+00, 9.52030649e+00, 7.42601279e+00,
        4.86924384e+00, 4.65123572e+00, 3.42272331e+00, 3.72094392e+00,
        3.79496877e+00, 3.63692105e+00, 4.53843102e+00, 4.49938710e+00,
        1.16647181e+00, 1.57530039e+00, 1.38785612e+00, 2.93999569e+00,
        3.19698360e-01, 1.09373256e+00, 8.91772857e-01, 1.27258163e+00,
        7.30115016e-01, 6.48975286e-01, 9.53344198e-01, 7.10095320e-01,
        1.94587869e-01, 2.37110242e-01, 1.74995857e-02, 1.09717525e-01,
        2.49860304e-01, 1.73485239e-01, 3.15215749e-01]])
```

Are divergences filtered out from draws during sampling? How would you proceed to diagnose what is going wrong in this case?

Comment: You should take a look at https://docs.pymc.io/pymc-examples/examples/diagnostics_and_criticism/Diagnosing_biased_Inference_with_Divergences.html (note that it's currently in progress of being updated to better take advantage of ArviZ features). If you have any doubts about the notebook it's better to ask at https://discourse.pymc.io/

Comment: Thanks, @OriolAbril. I will read more of the notebook, although, since my question should be specific enough, probably someone can already indicate how to approach this problem in this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

I think this doc has a lot of what you need to know: https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/Diagnosing_biased_Inference_with_Divergences.html

But to summarise, you should know that understanding the divergences is a difficult problem in general and there isn't a silver bullet for it -- You'll have to try many (sometimes many many) things. Looking at the trace plots alone won't be enough. That being said, the document I linked you has a lot of good recommendations.

The general recommendation I can give is that you shouldn't focus on a specific sample that was divergent. That's meaningless. The thing that is diverging is not the sample but the trajectory. Use `arviz.pair_plot` and focus on where divergences concentrate (set `divergences=True`). Run much longer chains (more than 10k samples) so that you get a lot more divergences and can easily spot the pathological regions. Once you spot the pathological region, deciding what to do with it will depend on your specific model. Perhaps increasing the adaptation step, perhaps changing your priors, perhaps re-parametrizing your model.

Since you're talking about groups, I suspect you are using a hierarchical model. In which case I think the best approach would be to try an alternative parametrization. Look up for discussions about centred vs non-centred parametrizations in hierarchical models.

Best of luck in your divergence hunting! :)

Comment: Note: the link is dead by now